# Error creating spinner for android?

Tags: android

Hey so I am trying to create a spinner with different options and I keep getting these two errors for the two last lines. I am following this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#Populate so I am not sure why it is error-ing?

```
//Creating spinner for select/options
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.typeFieldWardrobeScreen);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,  R.array.type_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

//for line above
Multiple markers at this line
        - Syntax error on token "setDropDownViewResource", Identifier expected after this token
        - Syntax error on token ".", ... expected

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

 //for line above
 Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
    - Syntax error on token "adapter", VariableDeclaratorId expected after
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize that I had it outside of the onCreate method, and it cannot be outside of a method.